# Different output string if I use the cmd line vs a function

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm trying to transform a date format from `"PT10H24M30S"` to `"10:24:30"`.

I created the following function:

```
function PTTime([string] $time){
        $pattern = "(\d{2})+"
        $matches = $time | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches
        $newFormat += $matches.Matches | ForEach {$_.Value}
        $newFormat = $newFormat -Replace " ", ":"
        return $newFormat
}
```

However, if I call the function I got the output
`10 24 30` 
or

```
10
24
30
```

But in the other hand, If I execute the function commands 1 at a time on the command line I got the correct output when I print `$newFormat` `"10:24:30"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that `$newFormat` was a different type than `$returnValue`

PS was a bit miss leading here, because when I called `$newFormat | Get-Member` or `$returnValue | Get-Memeber`
the output type always is `TypeName: System.String`. 
However, if a do `$newFormat.GetType()` I got `System.String` while if I call `$returnValue.GetType()` I got `System.Array[]`.

I updated the function and now is working as expected

```
function PTTime([string] $time){
        $pattern = "(\d{2})+"
        $matches = $time | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches
        $newFormat = $matches.Matches.Value 
        return $newFormat -Join ":"
}
```